# Pivot / Aggregate scores within ranges?

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot

I have a table of approx 12,000 rows and each one has a "number of points".  I'd like to select the count of each number of rows where the points are in a range, e.g. 0 - 1000, 1000 - 2000, etc.

At the moment I am using the "long way round" method, but is there a much simpler way to acheive this?

```
select
  SUM(pts.[UNDER 1000]) AS 'UNDER 1000'
, SUM(pts.[UPTO 2000]) AS 'UPTO 2000'
, SUM(pts.[UPTO 3000]) AS 'UPTO 3000'
, SUM(pts.[UPTO 4000]) AS 'UPTO 4000'
, SUM(pts.[UPTO 5000]) AS 'UPTO 5000'
, SUM(pts.[UPTO 6000]) AS 'UPTO 6000'
, SUM(pts.[UPTO 7000]) AS 'UPTO 7000'
, SUM(pts.[UPTO 8000]) AS 'UPTO 8000'
, SUM(pts.[UPTO 9000]) AS 'UPTO 9000'
, SUM(pts.[UPTO 10000]) AS 'UPTO 10000'
from 
(
select
    case when HouseholdPointTotal < 1000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'UNDER 1000'
    , case when HouseholdPointTotal >= 1000 AND HouseholdPointTotal < 2000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'UPTO 2000'
    , case when HouseholdPointTotal >= 2000 AND HouseholdPointTotal < 3000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'UPTO 3000'
    , case when HouseholdPointTotal >= 3000 AND HouseholdPointTotal < 4000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'UPTO 4000'
    , case when HouseholdPointTotal >= 4000 AND HouseholdPointTotal < 5000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'UPTO 5000'
    , case when HouseholdPointTotal >= 5000 AND HouseholdPointTotal < 6000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'UPTO 6000'
    , case when HouseholdPointTotal >= 6000 AND HouseholdPointTotal < 7000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'UPTO 7000'
    , case when HouseholdPointTotal >= 7000 AND HouseholdPointTotal < 8000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'UPTO 8000'
    , case when HouseholdPointTotal >= 8000 AND HouseholdPointTotal < 9000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'UPTO 9000'
    , case when HouseholdPointTotal >= 9000 AND HouseholdPointTotal < 10000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'UPTO 10000'
from MRS_Retail_HouseholdPoints
) pts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure it's the best or most readable way, but.

You could do a select taking numbers from 1 to 10.

Which you can do this way

```
SELECT TOP 10 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number)  rn
  FROM [master]..spt_values
```

now, you build a CTE with this, which will give you a lower bound and an upper bound

(0-999, 1000-1999, 2000-2999) for example

```
with CTE as (select 
               (rn-1) * 1000 as low, 
               (rn * 1000)-1 as up 
             FROM (SELECT 
                    TOP 10 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number)  rn
                  FROM [master]..spt_values ) 
             s)
```

Of course, this part could be replaced by a table containing numbers, or lower and upper bounds, which would make things less "tricky" and more readable...

Anyway, with that, you can do a left join on your table, and build the labels (not exactly the same as you did, but...

So

```
with CTE as (select 
              (rn-1) * 1000 as low, 
              (rn * 1000)-1 as up 
             FROM (SELECT 
                      TOP 10 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number)  rn
                   FROM [master]..spt_values ) s
             )

  select  
   cast(low as varchar) + '-' + cast(up as varchar) as label,
   count(p.Id) as number  
  from cte c 
  left join MRS_Retail_HouseholdPoints p on p.HouseholdPointTotal between low and up
  group by  low, up
```

But this will return you rows, not columns.

So you'll need to pivot if you want columns

```
with CTE as (select 
               (rn-1) * 1000 as low, 
                (rn * 1000)-1 as up 
             FROM (SELECT 
                     TOP 10 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number)  rn
                   FROM [master]..spt_values ) 
                     s)
      select [0-999], [1000-1999], [2000-2999], [3000-3999], [4000-4999], [5000-5999], [6000-6999]--etc.
      from
      (select  
       cast(low as varchar) + '-' + cast(up as varchar) as label,
       count(p.Id) as nb
      from cte c 
      left join MRS_Retail_HouseholdPoints p on p.HouseholdPointTotal between low and up
      group by  low, up) p
      PIVOT (min(nb)
             FOR label in (for label in ([0-999], [1000-1999], [2000-2999], [3000-3999], [4000-4999], [5000-5999], [6000-6999]--etc))
    as  pvt
```

Not that readable, huh ;)

You may even do a dynamic pivot if you wanna avoid having to write the up and down bounds.